# if...else.. compare character list and string by python

Tags: python

I am writing an for loop comparing the character in list and string, then return False if the character is not same. But I keep receiving True. Can someone explain what is wrong with my code?

```js
def compare (sofar, orig):
    if len(sofar) == len(orig):
        for i in range(len(orig)+1):
            if orig[i] == sofar[i]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
            
    return False
```

here is the result i got:

```
In [29]: compare (['a','v','c','c','s'], 'abccs')
Out[29]: True
```

But it suppose to be False

Comment: You're returning True on the very first matching character...

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just join the characters back into a string

```
def compare (sofar, orig):
    return ''.join(sofar) == orig
```

Otherwise, if you wanted a loop, you need to compare **all** characters before you return True. You can return False when the first *does not match*

Here's another one liner using `all()` over a loop of zipped characters.

You will need the length check before this statement

```
return all(x == y for x, y in zip(sofar, orig))
```

Or going back to the original code, invert your logic

```
def compare (sofar, orig):
    if len(sofar) != len(orig):
        return False
    for i in range(len(orig)):
        if orig[i] != sofar[i]:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally understand whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your function reaches a `return` statement, that's it. Your function has returned a value and it will not continue running.

You can use a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) to implement your logic. The below solution allows you to iterate lazily; retrieve a Boolean list with a letterwise comparison via `list`; or check if all letters align via `all`.

```
def compare(sofar, orig):
    if len(sofar) == len(orig):
        for i in range(len(orig)):
            if orig[i] == sofar[i]:
                yield True
            else:
                yield False

res = list(compare(['a','v','c','c','s'], 'abccs'))

# [True, False, True, True, True]

res = all(compare(['a','v','c','c','s'], 'abccs'))

# False
```

---

Another way of writing your logic without explicit iteration:

```
lst = ['a','v','c','c','s']
mystr = 'abccs'

res = ''.join(lst) == mystr
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try you use generator. :)

Answer (score 0):

The statement return is exit from your function.
So your prog only compares the first element.

```
 if orig[i] != sofar[i]:
            return False
```

would do it